# Batch, How do I execute code stored in a variable or txt file?

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, batch-file, variables, cmd

How can I execute code saved in a variable?  I'm trying to execute an if statement that I have saved in another file (that must remain a text file). Clues on how to execute an `if` statement just from a variable might help, as I assume the problem is that it can't read the `%%s`.

Text file contains:

```
if %var%==0301 (echo Yay)
```

Batch file contains:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%s in (code.file) do (
%%s
)
```

This normally executes the code in `code.file` by setting everything in `code.file` to the variable `%%s` and then executing the variable.

The result is this: `'if' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

This method works for executing `echo` and `set`, but I need it to work for `if`.

Comment: Kindly exemplify

Comment: You haven't really posted enough code for us to give meaningful advice, but I will say that `%%s` only exists for the duration of the `for` loop, so if you're trying to use the value after the very last `)`, you'll need to do something like `for /f "tokens=*" %%s in (code.file) do set "value=%%s"` and then use `%value%` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IF` is detected by the parser in phase2 only, but `%%s` will be expanded in a later phase.

You need to use a percent expansion for it, like in this sample

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%s in (code.file) do (
  set "line=%%s"
  call :executer
)
exit /b

:executer
%line%
exit /b
```

But for your sample: `if %var%==0301 (echo Yay)`
It will never say `Yay`, because `%var%` will never be expanded.

This is because `%line%` is already a percent expansion, it will not work recursively.

That could be solved by changing the text in code.file to
`if !var! == 0301 (echo Yay)`
This works, because the delayed expansion happens after the percent expansion

Or a much simpler solution:

```
copy code.file tmp.bat
call tmp.bat
del tmp.bat
```

Answer (score 1):

The major problem at hand is that the command interpreter particularly handled the commands `if`, `for` and `rem`: These commands are recognized earlier than every other one, even before `for` meta-variables like `%%s` become expanded. Therefore, these commands are no longer detected after expansion of `%%s`.

Refer to: [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4095133)
According to this, said commands are detected during Phase 2, while expansion of `for` meta-variables happens in Phase 4. Other commands are found later in Phase 7.

A possible way to work around that is to use a sub-routine, which `%`-expansion occurs in, which happens in Phase 1, hence before recognition of the three special commands:

```cmd
for /f "tokens=*" %%s in (code.file) do (
    rem // Execute the read command in a sun-routine:
    call :SUB %%s
)
goto :EOF

:SUB
rem // Take the whole argument string as a command line:
%*
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Minor critics: Using `call :SUB %%s` and expansion of `%*` leads to new problems with string modifications by `call` and reduction by `%*`

Comment: Thanks!  I never even knew there were different phases!

Comment: @jeb, true. A possibility was to replace `call :SUB %%s` by `set "ARGS=%%s" & call :SUB %%ARGS%%` to solve issues with `call`, although this would still not execute the command line `if %var%==0301` in the sub-routine as expected…

Comment: But it still fails with `echo one & echo two`, I suppose arguments should be avoided at all in the CALL

Comment: You can use 'call :SUB' without parameters if you use a dummy for-loop in :SUB This works because all for-parameters are global inside a for-loop. Use in :SUB only the following line: 'for %%. in (.) do %%s'

Comment: Sure, @OJBakker, but then you'll have the same problem like in the original post…